# Puppet pass a fact into a double-quoted line of code in an ERB file

Tags: puppet, interpolation, erb, facter

I'm sure the answer to this is straightforward, but I can't find out how to do this.  I have a line in my erb template file that needs to write exactly as-is into a server's config file (for OpenVPN):

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.16.23.12"
```

I need to change this so that the ip address gets looked up from the facter listing on the server, rather than having it hard-coded, as this conf file needs to be used on different servers now.  The fact holding this ip address is "ipaddress_tun0".  I've tried putting it into my line, thus:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS <%= @ipaddress_tun0 %>"
```

.. but the fact doesn't get interpolated properly, presumably because of the double quotes.  Unfortunately the double quotes are needed as a literal part of the line in the conf file, so they have to be there (single quotes don't work).  Can anyone advise how I can get this line to look up and insert the value of ipaddress_tun0, please?

Comment: `push "dhcp-option DNS <%= @ipaddress_tun0 %>"` works for me no problem.  Have you tried running `facter ipaddress_tun0` on the machine to make sure it's actually a fact?  Or just run `facter` to see what your options for facts are, and make sure you have the correct fact name/spelling.

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely a fact (just double-checked) and the fact is correctly spelled.  In the end a colleague suggested I needed to use scope.lookupvar, so:

    push "dhcp-option DNS <%= scope.lookupvar('ipaddress_tun0') %>"

and this seems to work.

Comment: Ah I see, seems like the `ipaddress_tun0` was out of your current scope.  Thanks, I learned something too.  Glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
push "dhcp-option DNS <%= scope.lookupvar('ipaddress_tun0') %>"
```

was what was needed, as my fact was out of the current scope.

Comment: This became important in Puppet 4, as they changed the scoping rules so that only vars inside the current scope can be referenced with `@variable` [docs](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_scope.html)

Comment: Are you sure, @Frap?  Your claim seems to conflict with [the current (v4.4) documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template_erb.html#variable): "All variables in the current scope (including global variables) are passed to templates as Ruby instance variables, which begin with 'at' signs (@)."  IOW, "in the current scope" is not the same thing as "local to the innermost current scope".